# Changing to XFCE from LXDE

Tags: boot, apt, gui, lxde

Apologies if this seems straight forward but I've recently downloaded XFCE to replace LXDE environment.

I did this by using

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

and following all the instructions.

Then to remove LXDE I carried out:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove lxde
sudo apt-get clean
```

My problem lies that whenever I run

```
 startx
```

it still opens and runs LXDE? I know that I should be running

```
startxfce4
```

but I want to know how to completely remove LXDE? and understand how startx works?

Edit: Also how do I modify the startx file so that I can choose (if both are installed) which desktop environment I want startx to run?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I posted this question in the Linux Stack Exchange as well, and a user named Vasa1 suggested to check

```
apt-cache show lxde
```

which listed all the associated packages with lxde, and therefore since lxde is a meta package, I therefore had to delete and remove the other associated packages in order to run startx to boot xfce4.

Answer (score 7):

Follow the step-by-step guide provided by yours truly :-)

First install XFCE4 (consider also installing the `xfce4-goodies` package for extra visual candy)

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

Then list all installed LXDE-related apps

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep "^lx"
```

...and remove them

```
sudo apt-get remove lxappearance lxde lxde-* lxinput lxmenu-data lxpanel lxpolkit lxrandr lxsession* lxsession lxshortcut lxtask lxterminal
```

Note that alongside **lxterminal** also **pistore** will be purged! So if you want the Pi Store, don't remove the lxterminal package

During removal the `update-alternatives` script will be executed and set xfce4 as the default x-session-manager in `/usr/bin/x-session-manager`.

Reboot the RPi, for the changes to take effect.

Last but not least you should run the autoremove and autoclean command to clean any unnecessary packages

```
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
```

And you're all set! Enjoy the much more user-friendly XFCE.